# Change onhover to onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I use this code inside our header to display our cart.
Currently the dropdown is displayed on hover.

How can I modify this so that the dropdown is displayed `onclick`?

```
<a href="#header-cart" class="skip-link skip-cart <?php if($_cartQty <= 0): ?> no-count<?php endif; ?>">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Cart'); ?></span>
    <span class="count"><?php echo $_cartQty; ?></span>
</a>

<div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_content');?>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the javascript function?

Comment: Tried? What have you? Why didn't it work? Did you debug it? What were the results?

Comment: i believe its a css hover property, you first need to remove that property and then add a jquery .toggle() to toggle display of the element to the #header-cart element

Comment: it seems like framework, check included js, somewhere you can find on mouseover method, change it as click

Comment: I can see that this is developed using magento but I cannot give you an answer because lack of information on this question. Is this custom deveoped theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<a href="#" class="skip-link skip-cart <?php echo $_cartQty <= 0 ? 'no-count' : ''?>">


$('a').on('click',function(){$(this).attr('href','#header-cart')});
```

Comment: This will not unbind the hover event.

Comment: Really? apart from mouseover how about css :hover pseudo element?